# Spring Boot with gradle and Jacoco plugin

Tags: java, spring, gradle, jacoco

When I added Jacoco plugin into my project `apply plugin: "jacoco"`. And then unit tests with database integration aren't working.

Spring datasource config (application.yml):

```
spring:
  profiles: test
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    password: postgres
    testWhileIdle: true
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/atol-test
    username: postgres
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
```

I use 1.3.6.RELEASE version of spring boot and i configured Jacoco at following way:

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
    }
}
```

When I want to start unit test stacktrace gives me:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "test" are currently active).
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:180)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
```

Anyone knows whats going on (as I mentioned - without Jacoco everything works)?

Comment: What's the gradle taks that is failing

Comment: task test or when I run it by IntelliJ test runner

Comment: Have you tried removing your customization for jacoco, I mean, remove all the stuff that you have posted above and just use this line 'apply plugin: "jacoco"'

Comment: Yes but still failing same way

Comment: Could you provide a github-repo in order to check what's happening?

Comment: unfortunately I can't because it is private local repo

Comment: Try removing you business logic and posting a very basic project, I mean, a hello world for example